# How to download drivers manually for Windows Server 2008 r2 Standard edition?

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2

### What I m trying to do ?

I installed `Windows Server 2008`  on my laptop , an `Acer Aspire 5741G` series .
I want this pc to emulate a server environment in a local network . Everything seems to work fine except the fact that the `PCI simple controller` , `the Network adapter` and the `Ethernet controller` drivers have not been automatically
updated . Due to that fact I can't connect to the internet from that pc .

### What I have tried ?

I have tried downloading these drivers manually from an other pc and then I tried to install them on my laptop . It seems that I didn't find drivers that are compatible. Also I ve tried selecting drivers from the pc's embedded driver's list by right
clicking on the `driver's software name` and then choosing the `update driver software` option . This seems to be a very bad practice to solve the problem because I don't know if there are actually any compatible drivers in this list .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Go to the Acer support site](http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) and download the drivers for your model, windows 7 drivers should work.

Comment: Try this: How To Manually Install LAN Driver For Windows Server 2008 In Desktop PC
Read more at http://imacify.com/2013/08/how-to-manually-install-lan-driver-for-windows-server-2008-in-desktop-pc/#i8TkEHQgP0yXkpgD.99

Comment: **DO NOT** visit that link, that Jatin published people, its just full of ads